# Stop an img with an explicit inline width being larger than the parent div

Tags: html, css

I have user generated content that needs to scale to fit in the parent container.
I don't have control of anything inside the div.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 300px !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p><img style="width: 800px;" src="http://placekitten.com/g/800/200"><br></p>
    
    <p>
    Other content
    </p>
    <p>
    CSS IS AWESOME
    </p>
    
</div>
```

How to I keep the content bound?

Comment: You don't even have control of the html inside the container? Because if the `width` is set inline as you have in your example, it will override any css applied to it externally.

Comment: It's user content from a rich text editor, and in this example that's the html it generated for a dropped in image.

Comment: @Polyov if `width` is set, it will not override `max-width`, but if `max-width` is changed inline than it would be overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to specify for all children at any level have max-height of 100% of parent element :)

```css
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.container *{
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p><img style="width: 800px;" src="http://placekitten.com/g/800/200"><br></p>
    
    <p>
    Other content
    </p>
    <p>
    CSS IS AWESOME
    </p>
    
</div>
```

And I'd suggest you get rid of !important if nothing else is modifying element so CSS name would be justified for word Cascading :)

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're setting the image width inline to a set pixel width, but this will ensure the image never exceeds the bounds of it's container:

CSS:

```
img {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't have control of the img and it may not be an img tag. User content from a rich text editor.

Comment: The text will reflow.. an image with a fixed width will overflow the container div unless the size is overriden.